# An identity in Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider incompressible Navier-Stokes equations in $R^3$: $$u_t - \Delta u + (u \cdot \nabla)u + \nabla p = f$$
We know we can use Leray projector $\mathbb P$ to cancel the pressure term. My question is how to derive the following identity: $$\mathbb P f= f - \nabla \Delta^{-1} (\nabla \cdot f)$$

I know after applying $\mathbb P$ on the equation, we have $$u_t - \Delta u + \mathbb P (u \cdot \nabla)u = \mathbb P f$$

So my difficulty (probably a property of $\mathbb P$ that's unknown to me) is how to deal with $\mathbb P (u \cdot \nabla)u $.

Comment: Your identity has nothing to do with the Navier-Stokes equation, it is just the definition of the Leray projection.

Comment: @Héhéhé Why is it defined like this?

Comment: For you what is the definition of the Leray projection ?

Comment: @Héhéhé I just learned it and $\mathbb P: L^2 \rightarrow H$ and is defined by $\mathbb P u = h$ iff $u = h + \nabla g$ with $h \in H$ and $\nabla g \in G$

Comment: @Héhéhé I think in your answer below, the decomposition should be $f = \nabla q + \nu$.

Answer (score 1):

The identity 
$$\mathbb P\, f = f- \nabla \Delta^{-1}(\nabla \cdot f)$$
has nothing to do to do with the Navier-Stokes equation.

It can be seen either as the definition of the Leray projection, or as a consequence of the definition.

One can define the Leray projection by using the Helmholtz decomposition. It tells us that a vector field $f$ can be written as
$$f = \nabla q + v$$
with $\nabla \cdot v = 0$
and this decomposition is unique (up to an additive constant for $q$). Then we define $\mathbb P\, f = v$. Roughly speaking, $\mathbb P$ is the projection on the divergence-free vector fields.

The equivalence between the two definitions is proven for instance in http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~frweber/LectureNotesMCFD/NotesMCFD.pdf section 2.2.1